# Limiting access to folder based on session/cookies

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I want to control the access to a folder on my website. The folder contains `index.html` and a lot of other stuff, so I can't restrict access based on a verification on the index.php file, because people can still access placing `index.html` on the end of the url.

I searched about some solutions, but I'm very new to PHP, so I didn't understand very well.

I know I can place a `.htaccess` file that blocks access to the folder. But can this rule be conditional based on a Session?

I read something about using cookies to block, can this be conditional in `.htaccess` file?

Also, the folder I want to block have subfoders, does .htacess rules extends to the subfolders as well?

Answer (score 2):

basically what you have to is to redirect all requests to the folder to a custom script. the script handles the request, validates the session and decides what to return.

heres an example for the htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule !^foder1/folder2(/|$) index.php?file=%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Comment: Ok, I did this and it its redirecting, but when I get into the php file, verify and validate that the user has access, how do I redirect to the files?

I'm using `header("Location: http://myurl.com/folder");`, but it returns a loop error, probably because it keeps falling into the php file.